# Pesticide Edolan U

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I have recently become aware that old woolen blankets from the 1940:s to the 1970:s often contain the pesticide "eulan U 33" or "Edolan U" and wonder what is the best way to dispose of these. Ordinary burning is apparently not enough.

Answer (score 2):

It can be found that Edolan-U (Eulan-U-33) is

[image: Fig.1 - Edolan-U structure]
CAS 69462-14-2
1-chloro-*N*-[4,5-dichloro-2-(2,4,5-trichlorophenoxy)phenyl]methanesulfonamide sodium salt, or
sodium 1,4',5'-trichloro-2'-(2,4,5-trichlorophenoxy)methanesulfonanilide
(PubChem doesn't know it yet, only its free sulfonanilide "acid", [CID 13932360](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/13932360)),

according to the [PAN PesticideInfo.org database record](http://www.pesticideinfo.org/Detail_Chemical.jsp?Rec_Id=PC37299) (and combination with some other chem. DB searches), where you can find potentially useful regulatory info.